# Detect onScrollEndReached in react-bootstrap-table-next

Tags: react-bootstrap-table

I would like to know if there is a way to detect when the scroll reaches to the bottom in react-bootstrap-table-next so that I can fetch new data from api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

By using `window.AddEventListener` .
For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.AddEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.RemoveEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
}, []);

function handleScroll() {
    if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight) return;
    console.log('Bottom of table detected, fetch more items!');
```